# Type aliases for outer object as private scope parameter

Tags: scala, self-type, type-alias

I have this situation

```
object SuperHorribleLongName {
   trait X {
       private[SuperHorribleLongName] def internalGaga() : Unit
   }
}
```

and I'm trying to get something like this working:

```
object SuperHorribleLongName {
   private type Sup = SuperHorribleLongName.type
   trait X {
       private[Sup] def internalGaga() : Unit
   }
}
```

but that just gives me `"error: Sup is not an enclosing class"`... I also tried `type Sup = this.type`, but still it doesn't work.

Anyways to achieve a nice shortcut for my outer object when using as private scope parameter? I *do* want to keep the long name for the object, and I have *lots* of private methods, that's why it gets really in my way.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to use type aliases for member scoping.

Comment: I'd guess the same. Did you try putting the type alias inside X though? And possibly without the `.type`.

Comment: @mpartel -- I tried your suggestion. Same result, doesn't work. I also tried to use `import` with an import alias, still no luck.

Comment: The dumb solution, of course, is to simply not use a `SuperHorribleLongName` in the first place.

Comment: @Dan we'll its actually `DeterministicSkipOctree` which has a character count even higher than `SuperHorribleLongName`, and I really like to keep the name, but would like to use an abbreviation inside, as the `private[DeterministicSkipOctree]` really impair readability. I don't see why type aliases or import aliases shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm know sure it suits your hierarchy, but what about putting all you private methods in a

```
private trait Y {
```

Otherwise, you can always mimic a namespace :

```
object SuperHorribleLongName {
object SHLN { //Dummy alias
  trait X {
     private[SHLN] def internalGaga() : Unit
  }
}
type X = SHLN.X  //Lift into main object
}
```

It's not satisfying, since SHLN is visible, and turning it `private` prevents lifting X. And it's messy.
So, let turn the problem inside/out :

```
private object SHLN {
   trait X {
     private[SHLN] def internalGaga() : Unit
  }
}

//Expose the instance under wanted name
val SuperHorribleLongName = SHLN
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, as `X` should be visible, thus on the user side we have `SuperHorribleLongName#X` for example.

Comment: That's the drawback of namespaces, but you may lift the symbols you want to expose.  Anyway I've updated my answer with another approach.